# how to have multiple timers in alarm clock

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok this is what I am wanting to do. I have an alarm clock that can only have one alarm set at a time.

So I have tried several different ways to make multiple alarms. This is the code I am using.

```
private void AlarmClock_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string speech = e.Result.Text;
            if (speech == "set the alarm")
            { AlarmTime = "set"; Alexis.SpeakAsync("What time?"); }
            if (AlarmTime == "set")
            {
                foreach (string time in AlarmAM)
                {
                    if (speech == time)
                    { 
                        AlarmTimer.Enabled = true;                  
                        Alexis.SpeakAsync("Alarm set for " + time);
                        Settings.Default.Alarm = time; 
                    }
                }
                foreach (string time in AlarmPM)
                {
                    if (speech == time)
                    { 
                        AlarmTimer.Enabled = true; 
                        Alexis.SpeakAsync("Alarm set for " + time); 
                        Settings.Default.Alarm = time; 
                    }
                }
            }
            if (speech == "clear the alarm")
            { 
                 Settings.Default.Alarm = String.Empty; 
                 AlarmTimer.Enabled = false; 
                 Alexis.SpeakAsync("The alarm is no longer set"); 
            }
            if (speech == "what time is the alarm")
            { 
                Alexis.SpeakAsync(Settings.Default.Alarm); 
            }
        }
```

Now I also have the timer tic. How can I achieve lets say 4 alarm events? Everything I have tried only sets one alarm.

Do I need to create different properties and call them by different names?

**This is a scenario.**

```
Alarm #1: Set for 5:30 am

Alarm #2: Set for 10:00 am
Etc., etc.,
```

Alarm #1 is set. However anything I do to create a new alarm just updates alarm #1 to what Alarm #2 should be.

Comment: Sorry for the code, I am on my cellphone. It does not have a way to insert code

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple instances of the timer object.  Each one would be set to a different time.

Comment: One alarm is no big deal. It's just frustrating when one is set, then you forget and set another time. I am just trying to make it easier for me instead of having one alarm. But I will try doing it again. It did not work the last time created multiple instances. I have not gave it much thought over the last two years until a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the creation of a new alarm to a function, with an argument for alarm number determining the alarm name. Then run it four times.